# Showing another form when double clicking a specific column in a datagrid

Tags: datagrid, vb6

### I am now working with visual basic 6.0 for school project , i want to display a form when i double click a specific column in data grid,can anyone help me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will give you some idea of how to get started:

```
Private Sub DataGrid1_Click() 'event fired when user clicks the DataGrid
    MyValue = DataGrid1.Columns(0) 'retrieve value of first column of selected row
    NewForm.Show vbModal 'open another form
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the DblClick event and check for the .Col property

```
Private Sub DataGrid1_DblClick()
  Dim intCol As Integer
  intCol = DataGrid1.Col
  DoYourThing intCol
End Sub

Private Sub DoYourThing(intCol As Integer)
  MsgBox "column " & CStr(intCol) & " was double clicked"
End Sub
```